# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2. How to Solve?

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio

When querying the SQLite database, only 2 lines are displayed. Is it possible to fix this error?

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Category", null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                categoryList.add(new Category(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1)));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
            database.close();
```

Error:

```
Process: com.triangle.learningenglish, PID: 30477
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.triangle.learningenglish/com.triangle.learningenglish.Select.SelectCategory}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2
```

Comment: This means that there are only 2 rows in the table.

Comment: @forpas db has 11 rows. It may not be updated

Comment: If there were 11 rows you would not get that error.

Answer (score 0):

the reason for that error is you are not checking that if a cursor is empity. you just simply cycle over the for loop and retrieving the result which may have or have not a value.
i guess this line of code solves your problem

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Category", null);
            
int numberOfRows = cursor.getCount();
int counter = 1;
cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(numberOfRows !=0 && counter <= numberOfRows){
             categoryList.add(new Category(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1)));
             counter++;
             cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
            database.close();
```

Comment: Error remained.

Comment: @TriangleN yeah i was mistaken. but it is minor error just try make counter 1. because the minimum number of row should be 1. and if that did non't work probably you might have a logical error with the rest of your code.

Comment: I didn't change DB version